# How can I delete multiple rows in cascade deleting?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on MySQL. I have three tables like following:

```
USER           PRODUCT        RELATIONS
ID  NAME       ID  NAME       USER   PRODUCT
1   FOO        1   APPLE      1      1
2   BAR        2   CARROT     2      1
                              1      2
                              1      2
```

How can I do to delete on cascade all the rows on table RELATIONS when I delete any row related in USER or PRODUCT?

As I understand, I can't use foreing keys in third table because in both of their columns the values can be repeated

Comment: You understood it wrong. Not only you can, but you **should** create those FKs. The referencing column doesn't need to be unique, only the referenced column needs to.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand why you cannot use foreign keys on the third table, But when you make the User or Product Column on the Relations table foreign keys it will have no effect on duplicates, so adding the On Delete Cascade constraint is enough